# Setting "not_analyzed" for all strings in Elastic Search AWS managed instance does not work for me

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I deleted all data, deleted my index, and ran the following command after verifying there are no other templates:

```
curl -XPUT https://search-xxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_template/all -d '
{
"template": "*",
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_fields": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "omit_norms": true,
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
'
```

I then proceeded to add some documents, and expected the string fields to not be analyzed, yet I still get the same behavior: a warning from kibana when doing a visualization that the field is analyzed (hence split) so results are messed up (which they obviously are).

Running the following before adding any data successfully added a "not_analyzed" index instruction to the oneFieldThatCould property, so this does work in a single property case, but I need this to be a general rule for all dynamically added prooerties:

```
curl -XPUT https://search-xxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/production/_mapping/events -d '
{
      "properties": {
        "oneFieldThatCould": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: This template perfect and works as it should. Keep in mind though that if an index is created specifying some indexed properties explicitely, those will not be overwritten to be `not_analyzed`. Might this be the reason fo the confusion?

Comment: nope, all properties are dynamic, and i've deleted all my data.  something else is wrong, just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked, I deleted the index & type & all templates & all data, and now all strings are created with analyzed off.  Not sure there's a major difference between what I tried before and this code, but it works now so I'm not gonna argue :)

```
curl -XPUT https://search-xxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_template/all -d '
{
    "template":   "*", 
  "settings": {}, 
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": { 
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
'
```